# S3 to Redshift - Cross Account encrypted data issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kms

I did the following tasks between two of my accounts ( Dev and Prod ) and I am not able to copy data from S3 to Redshift in my Prod Account.

**Task 1:**

- I have some data in my Dev Account under S3
- This data is encrypted using KMS
- I wanted to move the same data to Prod Account
- I started a EC2 Server and executed sync command to move data from Dev to Prod ( My Bad I did not focused on decryption while syncing )
- My data is available in Prod Account ( around 500 GB )

  [image]

**Task 2:**

Now I wanted to move this S3 data ( Which is copied from Dev ) to
Redshift , I executed the following command using Redshift Query
Editor.

Command:

```
COPY table1(wre,sdf,sfd,sd,fs,df,sdfs,dfsdf,sd,fs,dfsdf,sdf,qwer,wer,wer)
FROM 's3://mydata/csv' 
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::myrole' 
DELIMITER '|' IGNOREHEADER 1 TIMEFORMAT 'auto' REMOVEQUOTES NULL AS 'NULL' 
EMPTYASNULL TRIMBLANKS ROUNDEC;
```

But I encountered the following error :

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403,
Error AccessDenied,Rid 70FE39F0982E9706,ExtRid Pxs9xdm+Plb2fvgySsuVq0UWLV2UCwMJ+qrGe0jazom346t4szXILbHma5SX1ZrIq4kPJA8q5Ws=,
CanRetry 1 Details: ----------------------------------------------- 
error: S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403,Error AccessDenied,
Rid 70FE39F0982E9706,ExtRid Pxs9xdm+Plb2fvgySsuVq0UWLV2UCwMJ+qrGe0jazom346t4szXILbHma5SX1ZrIq4kPJA8q5Ws=,
CanRetry 1 code: 8001 context: S3 key being read :
```

[image]

I thought that since the data is encrypted I am facing this issue. So in order to overcome this I tried to allow cross account access to the KMS.

**Task 3:**

I gone through [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policy-modifying.html#key-policy-modifying-external-accounts) document and followed the procedure. Here is the steps for the same and the policy which I have created .

- I created a IAM Policy ( described below ) in Production Account
- Attached this policy to my Role (Which is used in copy statement above) for Redshift copy in Production Account

Policy :

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUseOfCMKInAccount444455556666",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncrypt*",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
        "kms:DescribeKey"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXX:key/9821114k-mfdfki-7e8e"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowUseofCMKToCreateEncryptedResourcesInAccount444455556666",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "kms:CreateGrant",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-2:XXXXXXXXXX:key/9821114k-mfdfki-7e8e",
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "kms:GrantIsForAWSResource": true
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Where `XXXXXXXXXX` is dev account number and arn is Dev Account Key arn.

What other changes I will have to make to get this running and get my data into Redshift.

It will be great if someone could help me understand the background behaviour as well.

NOTE : I am using Customer Managed Key in Dev Account in KMS.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem like a KMS error.
You need to give Redshift permission to access the data in S3 Bucket.

> The user account identified by the credentials must have LIST and GET
>   access to the Amazon S3 bucket. If the user does not have sufficient
>   privileges, you will receive the following error message:
>
> ERROR: S3ServiceException:Access Denied,Status 403,Error AccessDenied

For more info see this link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/s3serviceexception-error.html

Comment: MyRole has full access to S3 and in that same bucket I have data that is not encrypted. This non encrypted data also copied from Dev Account and I can access that.

Comment: @ShivkumarMallesappa Not your role. You have to add a bucket policy to allow Redshift to access that bucket.